# Chain multiple RxJS observables and assign value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have properties

```
currentApplication: IApplicationModel;
logos: IImagesModel[];
backgrounds: IImagesModel[];
```

And I have three observables like this:

```
  loadApplication(): Observable<IApplicationModel> {
    return this.applicationService.getById(this.applicationId);
  }
  loadApplicationLogos(): Observable<IImagesModel[]> {
    return this.applicationService.getApplicationFiles(this.applicationId, "logo");
  }
  loadApplicationOldBackgrounds(): Observable<IImagesModel[]> {
    return this.applicationService.getApplicationFiles(this.applicationId, "background");
  }
```

and they do not depend on each other. I want to have ONE subscription, for example with mergeMap(), but I want also to assign the result of each observable.

```
this.loadApplication()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(application => this.loadApplicationLogos()),
        mergeMap(application => this.loadApplicationOldBackgrounds()),
        
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        
      })
```

How I can assign applications and logos to currentApplication and logos ? Should I use tap() before every mergeMap() or is there a better way with something different from mergeMap?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combineLatest to make all your calls at the same time and merge the results at the end:

```js
    combineLatest([
        this.loadApplication(),
        this.loadApplicationLogos(),
        this.loadApplicationOldBackgrounds()
    ]).pipe(
        map(([currentApplication, logos, backgrounds]) => {
            return {
                currentApplication,
                logos,
                backgrounds
            };
        })
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

It will emit when all observables have emit at least once.

Answer (score 2):

The perfect solution for you is proablt the `combineLatest` operator

```
combineLatest([
  loadApplication(),
  loadApplicationLogos(),
  loadApplicationOldBackgrounds(),
]).subscribe(([res1,res2,res3]) => {...})
```

The thing that will happen is once all three of your observables return something, you will go inside the `subscribe` and will recieve all data in an array, after that you can handle the data in whatever way you like it.

Comment: So, to follow up on my question, if for example in same component I have function to add new logo, should I again subscribe in that function with `loadApplicationLogos()` to get list of all logos?

Comment: This is a tough one without context, and now we are diving more in how you preserve state in your application (in this case the logos). 
So if after the first subscription you have stored the response in some variable you can use whatever you have already stored in that variable, for example `loadApplicationLogos().subscribe(logosResponse = this.logos=logosResponse)` after that you will be able to access the logos without making a new subscription.
Try finding some articles about statemangement without ngrx and things will get clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load all three in parallel, you can use `combineLatest` as others have mentioned. If you need to load the application first, you can handle it using something like this:

```
this.loadApplication().pipe(
    switchMap((application) => {
        return combineLatest(
            this.loadApplicationLogos(application),
            this.loadApplicationOldBackgrounds(application)
        ).pipe(([logos, backgrounds]) => {
            // create an updated application object with logos and backgrounds...
            return {...application, appLogs: logos, appBackgrounds: backgrounds};
        });
    })
);
```

Here's a tool that I found very helpful when learning RxJS:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#choose-an-operator

If you have complicated state management requirements and you're using a lot of RxJS, I recommend looking at NgRedux:

https://ngrx.io/docs

Comment: Nice article. So, to follow up on my question, if for example in same component I have function to add new logo, should I again subscribe in that function with `loadApplicationLogos()` to get list of all logos?

Comment: Actually you don't need the `of(application)` part inside the `combineLatest` as you will be able to access the `application` variable that comes as response in the `switchMap` also proably typeScript will tell you `You have shadowed variable 'application'`

Comment: @StefanT You don't need a subscription inside another subscription. The pipe() operator takes care of this automatically. You only need to worry about the subscribe() call at the tail end of the whole operation. In the code example I've given, I'm assuming that loadApplicationLogos() returns an Observable, not a Subscription. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

Frankly speaking, all depends on your expecations.
If you use `combineLatest` operator, that stream produces a new value every time the some of input streams produces value.
What's more, `combineLatest` runs observables in sequence

Probably, you want to look at `forkJoin` operator which runs observables in parallel. It waits on all observables have produces their first values and complete itself.

`forkJoin([loadApplication(),loadApplicationLogos(), loadApplicationOldBackgrounds()]).subscribe(([res1,res2,res3]) => {...})`

Comment: forkJoin works exactly like combineLatest except that it waits for all observables to complete and emits only once.

Comment: From your explanation, we could understand that the forkjoin will complete once every observables has emitted once, which is not how it works. It's not clear.

Comment: Please propose "edit", because I believe I wrote clear.